How to address vulnerability issue with protobuf
We have docker image where /opt/spark/jars/mesos-1.6.2-shaded-protobuf.jar is placed.
Security team reported that there is vulnerability issue CVE-2021-22569 in /opt/spark/jars/mesos-1.6.2-shaded-protobuf.jar related to com.google.protobuf_protobuf-java of version 3.5.0.
I've tried to find (over there https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.mesos/mesos/) the version which doesn't contain the vulnerability. And found that even the latest possible version of Mesos (1.11.0) still contains the vulnerability.
Any idea how to solve it?

Are you sure you need the shaded version? On a regular version where all dependencies are added as separate jar files you could simply use a different protobuf version (as long as the version is API compatible with the one included in mesos-1.6.2-shaded-protobuf.jar.
